# Can't get items in a ListView cross-thread

Tags: c#, listview, thread-safety, backgroundworker

My [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) needs to iterate through each item in a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However I can't do this:

```
foreach (ListViewItem Item in List.Items)
```

because it's a cross thread operation.

I also can't put the items in a [ListView.ListViewItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.aspx) and make the background worker read from that. This is still trying to access the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and creating a cross thread operation.

How can I make the [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s items available to the background worker without putting them in a variable somewhere?

Comment: There is a way to disable illegal cross thread operation checks, but the exact solution IS to put the data in a data access object or variable and update the list view when the background operation completes.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this function.

```
private delegate ListView.ListViewItemCollection GetItems(ListView lstview);

private ListView.ListViewItemCollection getListViewItems(ListView lstview)
{
    ListView.ListViewItemCollection temp = new ListView.ListViewItemCollection(new ListView());
    if (!lstview.InvokeRequired)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in lstview.Items)
        temp.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
        return temp;
    }
    else
        return (ListView.ListViewItemCollection)this.Invoke(new GetItems(getListViewItems), new object[] { lstview });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in getListViewItems(List))
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with mdb, but have to mention that depending on importance of application,

Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

can still be used as  a temp quick fix.

Answer (score -2):

try this.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
}
```

Comment: This is bad advice. Although it will get rid of the error message, you'll still be making cross-thread calls without any synchronization, potentially corrupting your results. The correct answer involves using delegates, as outlined in another reply.