# Loop through selected listview items in background worker

Tags: c#, listview

I am having a hard time trying to loop through all my **selected** items from my listview in a background worker. I did some research and found this; [Can't get items in a ListView cross-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022825/cant-get-items-in-a-listview-cross-thread) But it does not seem to work as I only want to send to **selected items** could someone give an example and an explanation as to what I should do? this is all very new and confusing.

Visual example of what i tired;
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your function `getListViewItems` expects `ListView` as an argument.  You are trying to call it with [ListViewItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.aspx) that is why it fails.

just modify it to

```
foreach(ListViewItem item in getListViewItems(listView2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Defint a function like this:

```
public static List<ListViewItem> GetSelectedListViewItems(ListView lv)
{
    if (!lv.InvokeRequired)
        return lv.SelectedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().ToList();
    else
        return (List<ListViewItem>)lv.Invoke(
            new Func<ListView, List<ListViewItem>>(GetSelectedListViewItems),
            lv);
}
```

Usage:

```
private void SendMSG_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in GetListViewSelectedItems(listView2))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: VladL is right, but I just wanted to provide a cleaner method to get selected items.